# Ajax Control Toolkit at Sharepoint How to install

Tags: development, ajax-control-tookit

I get a AjaxControlToolkit  from http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/
I used install by Toolkit via NuGet.
And i'm woried that it's get a lattest version of AjaxControlToolkit.

Now I'm getting a error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I tryed adding tio bin folder of sharepoint AjaxControlToolkit.dll, but it don't work. Meybe it that it was install via NuGet ?

Please help

Comment: How add assembly to GAC ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to [download](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Download.ashx) required dll and put it in gac followed by a IIS reset. Make sure you use right and reference same version of it in your project as there are many versions of AjaxToolKit dll also check if you are downloading 32 or 64 bit not sure if it actually matters as I downloaded 1 that worked on 32 and 64 bit operating systems.

Hoper it helps.

Comment: And how add to GAC ? Please. Only works 3,5 with sharepoint.

Comment: just copy ajaxtoolkit dll on your desktop and then navigate to "C:\Windows\assembly" folder and drag and drop ajax.. dll into folder, its not recommended but always works for me